# Dynamic regsub not replacing data

Tags: regex, tcl

I am using a variable in regsub.  But the data isn't being replaced.  If I use a bare word it works.

```
set d1 START2
set t "hello"
set data [regsub {(d1)} $data $t]
```

The above code fails to replace, if I use the below it works.

```
 set data [regsub {(START2)} $data $t]
```

I have tried the following variations, but they all fail.

```
set d1 "START2"
set data [regsub {($d1)} $data $t]
set data [regsub {(${d1})} $data $t]
```